# Magento2 setup error stating i need to change php.ini setting but it is already set

Tags: php, magento2, php-ini

I am trying to set up a Magento 2 app.

I keep getting an error like this:

```
Your PHP Version is 5.6.31, but always_populate_raw_post_data = 0. 
$HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA is deprecated from PHP 5.6 onwards and will be removed in PHP 7.0. 
This will stop the installer from running. Please open your php.ini file and set always_populate_raw_post_data to -1. 
If you need more help please call your hosting provider.
```

First of all I have 3 dirs: PHP5.6.31, PHP7.0.23, PHP7.1.9.
So in the PHP 5.6.31 i have 3 ini files all of witch have this setting.

```
always_populate_raw_post_data to -1
```

The other 2 folders PHP7.0.23, PHP7.1.9 don't have this in the php ini because it is newer version of php.   My question is what can i do to resolve this issue if the php ini does have the correct settings but the install says otherwise?

Comment: What exact version of Magento2 are you trying to install? and secondary: are you sure it is getting the correct php.ini file?

Comment: Magento-CE-2.1.11-2017-12-11-08-53-09 is the version.  and on the second question i guess so it is the php ini file in the PHP5.6.31 the other PHP folders have an ini but no setting like this always_populate_raw_post_data to -1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well Magento 2.1.11 does not support PHP 5.6.31, but only from 5.6.4 and upper. 
Have a look [here](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/install-gde/system-requirements-tech.html).

So, try first running

```
which php
```

to see which version it is trying to use, then either you can uninstall the 5.6 version and (better) use the php7 version, or be sure it is using the proper one.
Hope it helps.

Comment: I greatly appreciate your response and help doesnt look like to many people want to tackle this one.  To make thing short i need to adjust the 2 software versions to the correct version compatibility.  Which Magento is compatible with PHP 5.6?

Comment: I'm really sorry, I wrote wrong numbers and going to modify the answer. Yea you need do make them compatible. Actually I dunno how it is working with WAMP, but you should upgrade at least to 5.6.5 if you want to use M2.1.11

Comment: Thank you you were very helpful i got it to work.  I upgraded my php version to match.